# getting two rows instead of one when ca

Tags: sql-server, case-when

example:

```
--table for illustration--
create table #temp (dd int, typeId int, cl smallint)
insert into #temp (dd, typeId, cl)
values (1,681,75)
insert into #temp (dd, typeId, cl)
values (1,815,75)
insert into #temp (dd, typeId, cl)
values (2,681,75)
insert into #temp (dd, typeId, cl)
values (2,815,75)
insert into #temp (dd, typeId, cl)
values (3,681,75)
insert into #temp (dd, typeId, cl)
values (3,681,100)
insert into #temp (dd, typeId, cl)
values (4,681,75)
```

query that i am looking for should come with unique dd (first column)

```
select distinct dd, case when typeId = 681 then 'True'
end as BDFlagStatus,
case when typeId = 815 then 'True' 
end as ODFlagStatus
from #temp
```

resut is...

```
dd  BDFlagStatus    ODFlagStatus
1   NULL    TRUE
1   TRUE    NULL
2   NULL    TRUE
2   TRUE    NULL
3   TRUE    NULL
4   TRUE    NULL
```

I am looking for ...

```
dd  BDFlagStatus    ODFlagStatus
1   TRUE    TRUE
2   TRUE    TRUE
3   TRUE    NULL
4   TRUE    NULL
```

Comment: `select distinct` is very limited in capability, but `GROUP BY` with aggregate functions like MAX() can do a lot more

Answer (score 1):

Try this .
[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a66f7/9) demo

```
    SELECT   dd
    ,MAX(CASE 
        WHEN typeId = 681
            THEN 'True'

        END) AS BDFlagStatus
    ,MAX(CASE 
    WHEN typeId = 815
            THEN 'True'
        END) AS ODFlagStatus
FROM #temp
group by dd
```

Comment: @VipulJhunjhunwala Jhunjhunwala It is a good habit to mark the answer as accepted if it is working :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
;with cte
as
(
select distinct dd, case when typeId = 681 then 'True'
end as BDFlagStatus,
case when typeId = 815 then 'True' 
end as ODFlagStatus
from temp
  )
  select dd,max(BDFlagStatus),Max(ODFlagStatus)
  from cte group by dd
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aa8a6/2)